# Issue with high resolution images in chrome(windows) loading from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am having a problem with a site. My problem is I am loading several images progressively - starting with a small resolution image for fast loading I am then ajaxing a bigger image in (normally the original size that a user uploads).

The code below works perfectly. HOWEVER when done on chrome on windows. if the bigger image is a really high res (lets say 4400 x 4000). The screen would go white and the image would disappear. The white bursts out of the container (which has overflow:hidden) on it and covers the screen. Only the elements with a higher z-index over the image displays.

If I inspect the element that is white. It shows that it is the element, and the image is loaded - the URL is fine and if I click the image to open in another tab it loads fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
if(href){


   var img = document.createElement('img');
   img.className = 'openLBFullView hidden';
   img.onload = function(){
       loadBiggerImg(this);
   };

   $(img).data('url',$currentImg.data('url'));
   img.src = href;
   img.id = 'my-image';

}

var loadBiggerImg = function(img){
     var originalImg = $('#my-image');

     //append the img to the document
     originalImg.before(img);

     // append original styles and classes to new image
     $(img).attr('style',originalImg.attr('style'));
     $(img).attr('class',originalImg.attr('class'));

     // fix for windows IE adding attributes
     $(img).removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');

     //fade in new image over the top and remove old one
     $(img).fadeIn(200,function(){
        originalImg.remove();
     });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions - [large images dont render in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524424/large-images-dont-render-in-chrome)

This not neccesarily will fix your issue though - I'd try using lowres jpegs scaled to highres and preload big one - once loaded fade lowres one and show the big one (in a way fake the progressive JPEG) - Hope that helps man.

Comment: Well I have tried that solution where I am using a low res image and and preloading the big one. I am kind of doing this here but instead of replacing the SRC with the high res I am adding it to the DOM and fading it in. 

I have done it switching the SRC and still get the white explosion on my screen.