# Large png files won't render in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: image, google-chrome, chromium

I am using Chrome (87.0.4280.88) and Chromium (87.0.4280.88) in Ubuntu 20.04. I have two versions of a png image, one less than 80MB and the other 110MB. When I open the smaller version (right click > open with Chrome or Chromium) the image renders just fine. However, when I try to do the same with the larger file the image won't be rendered in either browser (see [image]). The large png is rendered in Firefox, so I know it is a valid file. I have tried to load the large png through html/javascript using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524424/large-images-dont-render-in-chrome) solution but it won't work. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Can you try it on Windows or macOS too? If it's a bug then it's better to file a bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @Asesh thanks for the suggestion. I tried it in Windows 10 within a virtual machine and the problem persists